# Do you think MongoDB is a good choice for large scale image retrieval system?

Tags: mongodb, search-engine, binaryfiles

At the present stage I am searching some alternatives for my futuristic image retrieval project. Some of my friends suggest to use MongoDB for searching and indexing backend. I am a bit biased for this. I don't know whether MondoDB might give fast enough speed for retrieval of about ~10 million images. What is your suggestion for these arguments?

My basic retrieval operation is cosine distance with LHS on image features. Please consider the question in these terms.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific -- what exact operation are you worried about, and what does the code look like for the operation -- without that this it is just a question attracting opinions rather than facts.

Comment: MongoDB will be good (scalable, redundant), use its GridFS.

Comment: ther is no code availabe I am at the preparation  phase so that is whay I am searching for the backend right now. My basic retrieval operation is cosine distance with LHS on image features

Answer (score 2):

You shoud keep in mind that if you are gonna use mongodb for Imgae File Storage, your images file size couldn't be more than 16MB unless you use gridfs

http://java.dzone.com/articles/when-use-gridfs-mongodb

You can gain great performance via mongodb. In my opinion if you want use your system just for Adding data and performing query (but not deleting and modifying them) Mongo is great